# Show a single item of an arrray

Tags: php, arrays

I am having a bit of trouble getting a single item shown/echoed in a foreach loop. What I mean I have an array (filled from database).

```
return array(
    'FriendName' => $FriendName,
    'FriendImage' => $FriendImage
    );
```

What I want is to show only `FriendName` while in a loop.
I have tried and this is an example:

```
foreach($UserFriends as $item) {
    echo $item['FriendName'];
}
```

But it shows NULL and not the data I expect.

Comment: it shows NULL but the data should show

Comment: Why do you need the loop in this case? What about - `$UserFriends['FriendName']`?

Comment: you should use `var_dump($UserFriends);` to see how is your array, then you will be able to code properly something perfectly adapted ;)

Comment: i want to fill this array from database of friends then print thought it may be better then querying the database more then needed.

Comment: When in your code do you assign the array values to $UserFriends? Looks like the array is empty! Can it be that it will contain more than one item?

Comment: yes in my code i assign values from a database that maybe where im going wrong

Answer (score 3):

No need for a loop if you just need one value, you can use this instead:

`echo $UserFriends['FriendName']`

---

Learn more about php [Arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Answer (score 1):

Its been better to use it directly instead of looping an array if its not multidimensional array you can simply get it using

`$UserFriends['FriendName']`

Answer (score -1):

you can checked using if condition like

```
foreach($UserFriends as $key => $item) {
    if($key == 'FriendName'){ 
        echo $item;
    }
}
```

your array is not multidimensional so you can access vlaues like that.

or else you can get a value directly like

```
echo $userFriends['FriendName'];
```

I hope this is working for you

Comment: i just tried this and now nothing shows maybe its not get filled right? I will try some more and get back to you all. Thanks for the help.

Comment: i am also filing array within a function then calling i from another page.the first array i have is working but i don't use it in a foreach loop

Comment: Your first example is an anti-pattern, the for-if antipattern. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/12/27/10251210.aspx